# API Key not working - Yesmail

Tags: php, api, curl

I haven't worked with API's before, i am trying to connect to the Yesmail API using PHP Curl, but i am getting an error `{"fault":{"faultstring":"Failed to resolve API Key variable null","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.oauth.v2.FailedToResolveAPIKey"}}}`

Yesmail API Documentation - https://developer.yesmail.com/yesmail-api-overview

Example code:

```
//CURL 
$apiKey = 'xxxxxxxx';
$url = 'https://api.yesmail.com/connect/my/api' .$apiKey;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r(json_decode($response, true));
```

Any ideas what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: What API are you trying to use (Subscribers, Emails, Tickets, Reference-Data, Target Lists)? The URL `https://api.yesmail.com/connect/my/api` is not a valid API endpoint.

Comment: Also, see the [curl Sample page](http://developer.yesmail.com/curl-sample) which shows a command-line curl example. You should be able to translate that sample to a PHP curl example.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are sending the API credential is wrong. You have to do it like this way:

```
$api_user = "YOU_KNOW";
$api_key = "YOU_KNOW";
$url = "https://api.yesmail.com/v2/subscribers";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Api-User: $api_user", "Api-Key: $api_key"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```